# Can we compare data type in javascript runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to compare the data type of object in javascript run-type by typescript class or interface.

ex:

```
interface IresponseObject{
 data:{name: string},
 errors:[]
}

const responseObject1 = {
   data: {name:"res"},
   error:[]
}

const responseObject2 = {
   data: {name:"res"},
   error:{}
}

function test(responseObject:IresponseObject) {
 if(responseObject instanceof IresponseObject) {
   console.log("true")
 } else {
     console.log("false");
 }
    
}

test(responseObject1) // true
test(responseObject2) // false
```

Comment: No, types are erased during runtime.

Comment: Not built in, but this might be of interest.. https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime